# Images out of "sync"

Tags: java, graphics

I've been creating a game in Java as a bit of a fun side project over the last few months and I've come across a really peculiar problem, take a look at this image:

[image]

The game is made up of various entities and elements that are all rendered onto the screen in one big for loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < level.entityList.size(); i++){
    if(level.entityList.get(i) != null){
        level.entityList.get(i).render(renderer);
    }
}
```

Now the render function within the entities allow them to render onto a buffered image which is then drawn onto the main canvas using `BufferStrategy.getGrapghics()`.  The problem is sometimes some elements will get rendered out of "Sync" from the rest of the elements. For example, sometimes the "Multiplier x1" and the top left of the screen will shift up a bit or down a bit even though everything is getting rendered onto one plane before being rendered onto the screen.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? (Sorry if this is confusing, I don't really know what to say)

Preview of glitch:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=u9yDlhJV_6I#t=69s

Comment: Are there any particular circumstances that cause it to happen?  Does it happen for just a moment or does it stick?  Can you quantify the difference between correct and not?  The more detail the better!

Comment: It does it at random intervals for what I assume to be a single frame at a time, but its very noticeable.

Comment: i'm just uploading a video to YouTube now to show you what I mean.